# Order by: Difference between two columns

Tags: php, sql, difference, sql-order-by

i have a question about a sql query. I have two columns in table users:

Moneytotal and Moneythisweek

Right now i would like to order the results on difference. 
How bigger the difference between Moneytotal and Moneythisweek the higher on the ranking.

Normally i use:

```
$lsel_rank = mysql_query("select * from users ORDER BY Moneytotal DESC");
$rank = mysql_fetch_array($lsel_rank);
```

But now i want to do something like:

```
lsel_rank = mysql_query("select * from users ORDER BY Difference between Moneytotal         
AND Moneythisweek DESC");
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY Moneytotal - Moneythisweek DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just simply use this

```
$lsel_rank = mysql_query("select *,'moneytotal - monethisweek' as difference from users ORDER BY difference DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: (Doing calculation in orderby)

```
SELECT * FROM `users` ORDER BY (Moneytotal - Moneythisweek) DESC;
```

Option 2: (Using numbered index in order by and calculating the difference and make available in the select query's resultset

```
SELECT (Moneytotal - Moneythisweek) difference, a.*  FROM `users` a ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```